# Rails: Calling Render From Within a Generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, generator, slim-lang

I've just started experimenting with generators. In one of my generated view templates, I want to call `render` like so:

```
index.js.slim
  transition("#main", "<%= escape_javascript(render 'index') %>");
```

When I try using the generator, I get this error:

```
(erb):1:in `template': undefined method `render' for #<Slim::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator:0x000000041b2a20> (NoMethodError)
```

Is Rails really incapable of calling `render` from within a generator? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[Railscast 218](http://railscasts.com/episodes/218-making-generators-in-rails-3?view=asciicast) goes into more detail:

> The first thing to note is that because we’re using the template
>   method, all of the erb tags in the code will be executed when the
>   generator runs. If we want to include any erb in the generated file
>   we’ll have to escape the percent sign at the beginning of each erb tag
>   and we’ve done that for most of the erb code above.

In this instance:

```
transition("#main", "<%= escape_javascript(render 'index') %>");
```

should become:

```
transition("#main", "<%%= escape_javascript(render 'index') %>");
```

All it needed was an extra `%` to escape the erb.